# Type mismatch. Required: Callback<AuthenticationResponse!>! Found: ` `

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

There is error in my code in this line

```
.enqueue(object : Callback<AuthenticationResponse>
```

```
Type mismatch. Required: Callback<AuthenticationResponse!>! Found: ` `
```

I am trying to call a login API when a user log in the response should be a token and a refresh Token that will be generated and will be used as a bearer token for other API

```
no the complaints snippet is  val email = bindingNotNull.editTextEmail.text.toString()
                val password = bindingNotNull.editTextPsw.text.toString()

                // Check if email and password are not empty (add additional validation as needed)
                if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
                    // Create an instance of the AuthService
                    val authService = RetrofitInstance.createAuthService()

                    // Create an AuthenticationRequest object with user input
                    val authenticationRequest = AuthenticationRequest(email, password)

                    // Call the login method in AuthService
                    authService.login(authenticationRequest).enqueue(object : Callback<AuthenticationResponse> {
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthenticationResponse>, response: Response<AuthenticationResponse>) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                                val authenticationResponse = response.body()
                                if (authenticationResponse != null) {
                                    findNavController().navigate(LoginNewFragmentDirections.actionLoginToDashboard())
                                } else {
                                    val errorMessage = "Response body is null. Login failed."
                                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                            } else {
                                val errorMessage = "Login failed. Please check your credentials."
                                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthenticationResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                            val errorMessage = "Network error. Please check your internet connection."
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    })


                } else {
                    // Handle case where email or password is empty
                    val errorMessage = "Please enter both email and password."
                    // Show an error message to the user, e.g., using a Toast
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it a complete snippet? The last 'else' is not preceded by 'if,' and the cause of the problem might be a syntax error.

Comment: No, I updated the code snippet

Comment: in the updated version there is one redundant closing curly brace, can it be the reason?

Comment: No, but I resolved it; it turned out that I was importing the wrong AuthenticationResponse data class. Thank you so much for taking the time to assist me regardless.